# SQL ERROR 1005. MariaDB

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

Estoy haciendo un entregable de la universidad por lo que no podré pegar todo el código. Cuando ejecuto mi código me sale lo siguiente:

> Error de SQL(1005): Can't create table `grados`.`groups`
>   (errno:150"Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed").

Tras darle a aceptar me sale otra ventana que dice:

> Warning: Create table  `grados`.`classrooms`not found in the data
>   dictionary near 'FOREIGN KEY (classroomId) REFERENCES
>   Classrooms(classroomId), UNIQUE (name,YEAR, subjectId), CONSTRAINT
>   negativeGroupYear CHECK(year>0), CONSTRAINT invalidGroupActivity CHECK
>   (activity IN ('Teoría','Laboratorio')) )'.

Tengo multitud de relaciones en las que he relacionado las claves ajenas con la misma sintaxis. He ido comentando el código para ir probando relación a relación y observar donde está el error, llegando a la conclusión de que el error se produce siempre que añado como clave ajena la clave primaria de Classrooms o bien la de Offices. Siendo subtipo estas de la relación AvailableSpaces. Aquí el código de estas relaciones:

```
CREATE TABLE AvailableSpaces(
    spaceId INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    nameSpace VARCHAR(32) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    floorSpace INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(spaceId)
);

CREATE TABLE Classrooms(
    classroomId INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    hasProjector BOOL NOT NULL,
    hasMegaphone BOOL NOT NULL,
    capacity INT NOT NULL,
    spaceId INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (classroomId),
    FOREIGN KEY (spaceId) REFERENCES AvailableSpaces(spaceId)
);

CREATE TABLE Offices(
    officeId INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    isShared BOOL NOT NULL,
    capacity INT NOT NULL,
    spaceId INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(officeId),
    FOREIGN KEY(spaceId) REFERENCES AvailableSpaces(spaceId)
);
```

Añadir además que si veis algún error en el código de error, alguna errata, es mía porque he escrito el error a mano porque no se copiarlo y pegarlo.
Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Debes poner el `CREATE TABLE` del error, no es ninguno de los que tienes en tu pregunta. Es el de la tabla `groups`. Otra cosa es que, tendrías que poner el `ENGINE` ya que si mal no recuerdo, tiene por defecto `MYISAM`, que no admite integridad referencial, todos tus `CREATE TABLE` deberían terminar así: `CREATE TABLE ( -- aquí las columnas y las restricciones ... ) ENGINE=InnoDB;`

Comment: Yo he probado tu código y funciona bien